# NSLog stops printing after third variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

I'm currently working on a Bluetooth LowEnergy application where I would like to use NSLog to print my gathered Information.

This is the code I'm using at the end of my didUpdateValueForCharacteristic Method when all properties are already update (debugger confirms that):

```
NSLog(@"These are the information I found! %huBPM Position:%@ Hersteller:%@ ", self.heartRate, self.bodySensorLocation, self.manufacturerName);
NSLog(@"Modell:%@ SerialNumber:%@ Batterie:%@", self.modelNumber, self.serialNumber, self.batteryLevel);
```

The properties are really just standard:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *manufacturerName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *modelNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *serialNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *batteryLevel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bodySensorLocation;
@property (assign) uint16_t heartRate;
```

What NSLog outputs is the following:

```
2014-05-14 11:04:16.888 PulseSense[24493:60b] These are the information I found! 77BPM Position:Chest Hersteller:Polar Electro Oy
2014-05-14 11:04:16.889 PulseSense[24493:60b] SerialNumber:1312082746
```

I can't help myself why it wont print SerialNumber:self.serialNumber and Batterie:self.batteryLevel. I had both NSLog commands in one line before, but the same thing happened here. I got cut after printing the third property (so even SerialNumber was missing).

Any ideas?

Edit 1:
So I did some test and what happens is that Modell, SerialNumber and Batterie are all null with the first execution of my NSLog Statements. This stays for the first few iterations when finally the first String Modell becomes a real Value ("H7"). This is then the first time when NSLog only prints Modell and leaves the others out (as they are still null and will become a value one iteration later).

Comment: try clean and build once

Comment: it doesn't print to log message, or the variables?

Comment: you should single-step through the code in the debugger, to see exactly what is happening. or try using [my logging "framework"](https://github.com/michaelpeternell/MPLog) which tells you the filename and line number of the log message instead of the superfluous date and program name.

Comment: NSLog(@"Modell:%@", self.modelNumber);

NSLog(@"SerialNumber:%@", self.serialNumber);

NSLog(@"Batterie:%@",self.batteryLevel);

use this and now check where you are struck , also remove all breakpoint and test.

Comment: Are you looking at Xcode's console output, or at the device's console output?

Comment: I think the log messages are just coming from somewhere else. That's the easiest explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this kind of behavior when `NSString` objects contain nil bytes (`\0`). Here's a test program that illustrates the issue:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() {
    NSString *a = @"aa\0a";
    NSString *b = @"bbb";
    NSLog(@"a: %@, b: %@, end.", a, b);
}
```

Running the above program:

```
$ clang -framework Foundation test.m -o test && ./test
2014-05-14 13:11:52.912 test[17814:507] a: aa
```

So ensure that the string values you are getting from your BT communications channel do not contain nil bytes. If e.g. you are using `NSMutableData` as your buffer, remove any nil bytes from it before trying to decode it into an `NSString`.

Comment: there is just one problem with this theory: the NSLog-line of the OP contains `@"Modell:%@ SerialNumber:%@ Batterie:%@"` and the output first skips the Modell. Then it prints the SerialNumber, and then skips the Batterie. How do you explain this?

Comment: @Michael Good point — if that's not a mistake in the typing of the SO question here, then that log message could be coming from somewhere else. I suggest the OP use the debugger to verify this.

Comment: So I did some test and what happenes is that Modell, SerialNumber and Batterie are all null with the first execution of my NSLog Statements. This stays for the first few iterations when finally the first String Modell becomes a real Value ("H7"). This is then the first time when NSLog only prints Modell and leaves the others out (as they are still null and will become a value one iteration later). So I guess you're right, though I need to figure out how to fix this ...

Comment: @Evils: did you step through the `NSLog` statements with the debugger?

Comment: @Michael Yes I went through the statements with the debugger. The Log Message is definitely not coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @hasseg I got it working now or at least kind of. When I use a NSLog call for each property, all statements get printed continuously. So I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the strings being (null) in the first iterations and some optimizations that happen when Modell gets set and the others are still null. Therefore I mark your answer as correct as it's related imho.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the third item contains valid value to print and not just nil in that object

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `NSLog` statement skipping the "Modell" and then printing the "SerialNumber"? I think the log messages come from a different place than you think.

To solve this problem, you should put a breakpoint on the two `NSLog` lines and single-step through them. Then, one of two things will happen: Either, the breakpoint will not stop the program, because the log-output comes from a different place. Or, the breakpoint stops, and when you single-step through it, it just works.

Let me give you an example

```
// part 1 source
NSLog(@"These are the information I found! %huBPM Position:%@ Hersteller:%@ ", self.heartRate, self.bodySensorLocation, self.manufacturerName);
NSLog(@"SerialNumber:%@", self.serialNumber);

...

// part 2 source
NSLog(@"These are the information I found! %huBPM Position:%@ Hersteller:%@ ", self.heartRate, self.bodySensorLocation, self.manufacturerName);
NSLog(@"Modell:%@ SerialNumber:%@ Batterie:%@", self.modelNumber, self.serialNumber, self.batteryLevel);
```

This gives the following output

```
// part 1 output
2014-05-14 11:04:16.888 PulseSense[24493:60b] These are the information I found! 77BPM Position:Chest Hersteller:Polar Electro Oy
2014-05-14 11:04:16.889 PulseSense[24493:60b] SerialNumber:1312082746

...

// part 2 output
2014-05-14 11:04:16.888 PulseSense[24493:60b] These are the information I found! 77BPM Position:Chest Hersteller:Polar Electro Oy
2014-05-14 11:04:16.889 PulseSense[24493:60b] Modell:Audi SerialNumber:1312082746 Batterie:LiIon
```

When you are looking at "part 2 source" and compare it to "part 1 output", it seems like it doesn't work. This can be worse, when maybe the "part 2 source" is never executed.

The underlying problem with `NSLog` is just that you can never be sure where the message came from. Just because you see `NSLog(@"hello");` in the source, and the log says `hello`, doesn't mean that the NSLog-line you are seeing was the one that produced the log output. There can be multiple places in the source that `NSLog(@"hello")` and only one of them produced the output.

To fix this problem for the future, you may use a logging framework that tells you the filename and linenumber of the log entries you are making. (e.g. with [MPLog](https://github.com/michaelpeternell/MPLog) (opensource, made by me) )